# links not working with masonry container below it

Tags: html, css, hover, jquery-masonry, tumblr-themes

I cant figure out why my hover state on the header link is not working? The only thing that I have deduced is that it has to do with the masonry container below it. Has anyone else figured out how to get around this? or what I am doing wrong.

I should also note: that the link does not work at all on browser, but interestingly the link works for mobile. *(chrome 37.0 mac) (iphone ios 8 safari & chrome)*

Live demo:
jamesdolencedemo.tumblr.com

I know tumblr makes a mess of code so I have attached the theme html along with the css

THEME:

```css
/*
YUI 3.14.1 (build 63049cb)
Copyright 2013 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the BSD License.
http://yuilibrary.com/license/
*/

html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}#yui3-css-stamp.cssreset{display:none}span {text-decoration: none;}

/*
James Dolence 2.00
Logan Myers 2014
*/
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
body {background: rgba(255,255,255,0);color: rgba(0,0,0,1);font-family: "Founders Grotesk";}

a {color: rgba(0,0,0,1); text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: rgba(0,0,255,1);}


.container {width: 90%; max-width: 1250px; margin: 0 auto;}


header nav {width: 97%; margin: 3em 1% 3em; background: rgba(0,0,255,1); float: left;}
header nav h1 a {font-size: 300%;}

header.try2 {width: 97%; margin: 3em 1% 3em; background: rgba(0,0,255,1);}


footer {overflow: hidden; width: 97%; margin: 7em 1%;}

figcaption p {padding-bottom: 1em;}

img, iframe {width: 100%; height: auto;}

div.container {border-bottom: 7em solid rgba(0,0,0,1);}

/*photoset fix to just show 1 image */
#index .photoset a img {display: none;}
#index .photoset a img:first-child {display: block;} 



.column.w1, .column.w2, .column.w3 {margin: 0 1% 1em; display: block; float: left;}
.column.w1 {width: 31%;}
.column.w2 {width: 64%;}
.column.w3 {width: 97%;}

#index:after, body:after, .container:after, #index:after, #index:before, header:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }


::-moz-selection {color: rgba(255,255,255,1); background: rgba(0,0,255,1);}
::selection {color: rgba(255,255,255,1); background: rgba(0,0,255,1);}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 
 .perma .column.w1 {width: 64%}
 .perma .column.w2 {width: 97%}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .perma .column.w1 {width: 97%}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>James Dolence</title>
 <meta name="description" content="James Dolence" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="James,Dolence,design,designer" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hi.iamloganmyers.com/jd/jd_tumblr.css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>



<div class="container"> 
<header>
 <nav>
 <h1><a href="http://google.com">James Dolence</a></h1>
 </nav>
</header>


{block:IndexPage}
<section id="index">
 {block:Posts}
  {block:Photo}
  <article class="column w1 post">
   <a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"></a>
  </article>
  {/block:Photo}

  {block:Photoset}
  <article class="column w1 post photoset"><a href="{Permalink}">
   {block:Photos}<img alt="" src="{PhotoURL-500}">{/block:Photos}
        </a></article>
  {/block:Photoset}
  
 {/block:Posts}

 {block:Pagination}
  <div class="pagination">
   {block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">-</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
   {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">+</a>{/block:NextPage}
  </div>
 {/block:Pagination}
</section>
{/block:IndexPage} 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/3fbycwu/87Hn3ipdt/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/3fbycwu/Sk0n3ipfd/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/3fbycwu/0BCn3ipcz/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
  var $container = $('#index');
      $container.infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : ".pagination",            
          nextSelector : ".pagination a:first",    
          itemSelector : "article",
          transitionDuration: 0,
          bufferPx     : 0,
          done : "",
          loading: {
              finishedMsg: "<p> </p>",
              img : " ",
              msg: null,
              msgText: "<p> </p>"
          },
      },
        function( newElements ) {
              var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
              $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                  $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems);
              });
            }
      );
      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry();
      });
  })();
 </script>  

 


<footer>
 <a href="mailto:jamesdolence@gmail.com">Jamesdolence@gmail.com</a>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

*Obviously if you run it, it is going to look messed up on here...*

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, so I guess I will answer it myself for future people...

It has something to do with tumblr's iframes it uses... Their z-index is set to z-index: 9999999998;
so it's a pretty simple solution of just changing the z-index of your element to something larger seems to fix it.

*(also that's why it was working for mobile because those iframes are different for that...)*

L